# Correct way of implementing class impossible to instantiate

Tags: java

**Short:**

Do I need to do something else but leaving out constructor?

**Long:**

I want to implement class which cannot be instantiate. I have find example in Math class here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

So I would write same thing:

```
public final class MyClass{

    public static int doubleMe(int x){
        return 2*x;
    }
}
```

Constructor is absent, so instantiation should be impossible.

But I am not sure about making my class final. Maybe (not necessarily) I would like to extend it in the future (eg. public class myClassB extends myClass) and this keyword will prevent it - so does it have to be there?.

Comment: Don't forget the default constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to do something else but leaving out constructor?

Yes. If you don't write a constructor yourself, Java will provide one.

You need to write your own *private* constructor:

```
public final class MyClass {
    // Prevent the compiler from supplying a constructor automatically.
    private MyClass() {}

    public static int doubleMe(int x){
        return 2*x;
    }
}
```

(I've fixed the name of your class to follow normal Java naming conventions.)

If you look at the source code for `java.lang.Math` you'll find a private constructor there for the same reason.

> But I am not sure about making my class final. Maybe (not necessarily) I would like to extend it in the future (eg. public class myClassB extends myClass) and this keyword will prevent it - so does it have to be there?.

You should only extend your class for reasons of polymorphism - which aren't relevant for a class which can't be instantiated.

Comment: +1 "You should only extend your class for reasons of polymorphism."

Answer (score 2):

> Constructor is absent, so instantiation should be impossible.

No - if there is no constructor declared, then Java automatically gives the class an implicit default constructor, with no formal arguments and no `throws` clause ([JLS §8.8.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9)). You need to explicitly declare a private constructor in order to make the class impossible to instantiate from the outside. Now as for your second concern: it makes no sense to extend a class that is impossible to instantiate, and hence it would make sense to declare your class as `final` - although this is not a requirement for making it un-instantiateable.

You might find the following section of the JLS relevant: [§8.8.10: Preventing Instantiation of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.10).

Comment: In addition, the default constructor would have to throw a runtime exception in its body, or else it would be possible to instantiate the class via reflection.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to making every method `static`, mark the class as `abstract`. This will prevent it from being instantiated.

```
abstract public class MyClass {
  ...
}
```

Creating a private constructor will prevent classes outside `MyClass` from constructing it, but won't stop one of the methods from within `MyClass` from doing it (private constructors are visible to the class itself).

Answer (score 0):

Use abstract instead of final.

Answer (score 0):

Use one (well, actually as many as you like) constructor and throw an unchecked exception from it.

Nobody will ever be able to create an instance of such a class.

Though, they can use static methods/fields of the class.

The approach sounds barbarian, but formally it will work.

Comment: yes... ok... but set this constructor as private, otherwise, it is in the public part of the class, it should work as if a moral contract... Imagine the situation: "Hello, I give you a nice appealing constructor for you to use, it is tempting isn't it? Use it ! Yes, you are now entering my super trap constructor and BOOM ! Exception ! MWAHAHAHAHA !"

Comment: I know, just was thinking of alternatives to million times discussed architecture. Actually the question was discussed a million times, again - just wanted some fresh ideas.